# Optimize mySQL query

Tags: performance, sql, mysqli

I have the following query:

```
SELECT tab.idtab AS id, tab.type AS type, COUNT( tablog.eDate ) AS times
FROM tab
LEFT JOIN tablog ON 
tablog.idtab = tab.idtab
AND tablog.event=  'ENERGY'
AND tablog.detEvent =  'KEEPALIVE'
AND tablog.eDate
BETWEEN  '2017-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-12-08 23:59:59'
WHERE tab.idtab LIKE  '%.%'
GROUP BY id
```

This returns a list of id from tab table with the amount times it received an ENERGY event between a given date in the tablog table. If there's is no appearences, it shows 0

The problem is that tablog is a large table, so it takes a long time to run. I need to speed this up a great deal. (this querie, for the example dates chosen, takes 22 seconds to run). It should be 2 seconds at worst!

Here's the EXPLAIN for the query:

[image]

I've tried doing a select inside select instead of left join, but it takes even longer. How can i improve the performance of a simple querie like this?

Comment: `LIKE  '%.%'` is not helping the performance. Why don't you create a dedicated column for it that indicates whether it's something with the `.`?

Comment: @t3chb0t I can't change the tables structure, i have to work with them as they are. I tried removing the LIKE '%.%' and then filter the results, but the querie takes even more (i assume its because there are a lot of id without the dot, and for each one i dont want, it looks for its count in tablog).

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There are few questions you need to answer.

1) The explain indicated that it had to examine 790,966 rows of the `tablog` table. Was that the total count of the rows? Or was it a fraction of the table? If it's the former, then that's very bad.

2) It's not obvious what is the `logUnique` key - if your query is going to always have the `event` and `detEvent` always hard-coded, then you are likely to benefit from having a composite index defined with `(idtab, event, detEvent, eDate)` which is more usable in the join since it can first look up the `idtab`, then jump directly to the `event, detEvent` that has the hard-coded criteria satisfied, then look at the `eDate`, yielding you a range seek. I do see that in the `Extra` column we have `Using index`, which is good, but it doesn't necessarily it's the optimum choice especially if it's just an index on the `idTab` alone or missing. You really want a covering index here.

3) Even given that the indexing on the `tablog` is optimum, you might need to consider whether you need to materialize the result of `tab` because the `%.%` is totally non-sargable as [t3chb0t](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/182617/optimize-mysql-query#comment347194_182617) noted in the comments. If there is truly only one row, then it'd be much faster to join with the materialized table. It may be more useful for you to run the query in isolation to help you see what's taking more time, the finding of qualifying rows in the `tab` table or matching the rows in the `tablog`. Compare this by running a query on `tablog` against a hard-coded list of `id` that you know to qualify and see what it looks like.

Good luck.